# Exclude folders while scanning the File System

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am running a backup service which scans the entire file system for .mp3, ms office files and .pst files and then store the files in a remote backup location. Can some one please tell me the list of folders which needs to be excluded while scan the file system(eg recycle bin, temp folder, etc)
Are there any more folders which i need not to scan?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you just scanned the user's personal folder? Instead of scanning the entire PC and excluding a few hundred folders...

Comment: I want to back the entire file system, its a backup service

Comment: I was able to exclude the standard folders using the Environment.SpecialFolder API

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a blacklist of directories, have a whitelist of directories.

This way it would also be easier to allow the user to add subsequent directories they want to add to their backup plan, and removes the danger of the application unintentionally scanning and/or backing up irrelevant files.

Answer (score 0):

Just give these options (of excluding/including directories of their choice) to user.